# Defining both strings and their union type concisely

Tags: typescript

I often need to have a set of valid string values AND a type, so I can do validation and whatnot. I don't want to repeat the same string multiple times. I came up with this:

```
export const animals = [
    "cat" as const,
    "dog" as const
];

export type Animal = typeof animals[0];
// type Animal = "cat" | "dog"
```

Is there a more concise way? It is a bit noisy.

I'd like to do

```
export const animals = [
    "cat",
    "dog"
] as const;

export type Animal = typeof animals[0];
// type Animal = "cat"
```

...but then I just get the type of the first string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index with `number` instead of `0`:

```js
export const animals = [
    "cat",
    "dog"
] as const;

export type Animal = typeof animals[number];
// type Animal = "cat" | "dog"
```